# Trouble with max_allowed_packet

Tags: mysql

I have a site using Drupal 7. Lately it has been having the following error message:

`PDOException: SQLSTATE[08S01]: Communication link failure: 1153 Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet'`

we tried to fix it by increasing the `max_allowed_packet` in mysql. That solve most of the problem but I am still having this error on some of the pages. The things is this occurs only when I am logging, anonyomus users has no such problem. Sometimes even the most simple page, like the About Us page, a simple Basic page with a piece of graphic, causes the error. Does anyone has any clue of what happens. My `max_allowed_packet` has been increased to 64M and the administrator hesitates to add more. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should investigate exactly what data (queries and their result) is travelling between PHP and MySQL.

Comment: I am a noob to mysql, so how should I do this? I cannot do it within Drupal, can't I? Any external tools I can use?

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have pages with lots of content, including documents (I am not sure if these are stored in the database, but some modules may do it that way). If you are not sure you can find out by examining the structure of the contents of the largest tables in your database look at the ones with the largest size per row (total size/ num of rows).
2. You can use this information to request your administrator to increase the packet size further so that the site works as you investigate.

Comment: largest as in the size of the table? That would be the "variable" table which take up 2.3 MB, the row with the largest size in this table is argcache_js_cache_files which takes up 1.2 MB (Its said in the table the value is (BLOB - 1.2 MiB), I download this and the resulting bin file is in fact 1.2 Mb. None other values has over 1Mib in size. I am a noob in this, but the max_allowed_packet in the server has already set to 64M, I don't see the problem there?